# jQuery mouseenter on paragraph with bold text

Tags: jquery, mouseenter, mouseout, paragraph, bold

I have a paragraph with a bold text inside

```
<p style="class1"><b>Some text</b> some other text</p>
```

and jQuery listeners for the `mouseenter` and the `mouseout` events of the `class1` elements

```
$('class1').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
});

$('class1').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("highlight");
});
```

where the `highlight` class is a style to simulate the classic HTML selection.

```
.highlight{
   background-color: blue;
   color: white !important
}
```

(I didn't used style1:hover cause i want to simulate programmatically also selection with arrows, but this is not really important now)

So, I have some paragraphs like this:

**Some text** some other text

**Some text** some other text

**Some text** some other text

Now, my problem is that when the mouse cursor passes from the bold text to the normal text (or viceversa), `mouseout` event triggers, loosing my fake selection but staying in the same paragraph. How can I avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use mouseleave event instead of mouseout..

```
$('.class1').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
});

$('.class1').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("highlight");
});
```

This will solve your problem..:)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the problem .. But let me advice you ... Never use the  tag! if you want a text to be bold, put a span on it and use the css font-weight:bold; ..

Comment: Using a styled span or a <b> tag is the same in this case, there's anyway a children in my paragraph.

Comment: In general, we should leave the style to the css. Especially the <b> tag, look here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_b.asp
"Note: According to the HTML 5 specification, the <b> tag should be used as a LAST resort when no other tag is more appropriate. The HTML 5 specification states that headings should be denoted with the <h1> to <h6> tags, emphasized text should be denoted with the <em> tag, important text should be denoted with the <strong> tag, and marked/highlighted text should use the <mark> tag.

Tip: You can also use the CSS "font-weight" property to set bold text."

Comment: I totally agree with you, but int this case it was not relevant, that's a post about event handling and cursor scopes, not about styling. I always use span or paragraphs to style, but to laziness i put here a <b> while developing.